# smtp authentication but rejected by spam filter

Tags: smtp, spam

Having a spam problem when I send the emails directly from my server, I asked my client to open an email account on her server.
I used smtp authentication with email address and email password. 
Here is the detailed answer of the server, can anybody explain me the reason that I cannot send and the solution please.
Thank you.

```
PEAR_Error Object
(
[error_message_prefix] => 
[mode] => 1
[level] => 1024
[code] => 10006
[message] => Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from 
server (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Rejected by spam filter (17211ed8-34a9-
11e7-9a8c-336c9f1d8145) [CSP-02])]
[userinfo] => 
[backtrace] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear/PEAR.php
                [line] => 577
                [function] => __construct
                [class] => PEAR_Error
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response 
 code received from server (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Rejected by spam 
 filter (17211ed8-34a9-11e7-9a8c-336c9f1d8145) [CSP-02])]
                        [1] => 10006
                        [2] => 1
                        [3] => 1024
                        [4] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [function] => _raiseError
                [class] => PEAR
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response 
code received from server (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Rejected by spam 
filter 
(17211ed8-34a9-11e7-9a8c-336c9f1d8145) [CSP-02])]
                        [2] => 10006
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear/PEAR.php
                [line] => 237
                [function] => call_user_func_array
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PEAR
                                [1] => _raiseError
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 
                                [1] => Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid 
response code received from server (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Rejected by 
spam filter (17211ed8-34a9-11e7-9a8c-336c9f1d8145) [CSP-02])]
                                [2] => 10006
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /opt/cpanel/ea-
php56/root/usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php
                [line] => 319
                [function] => __callStatic
                [class] => PEAR
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => raiseError
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid 
response code received from server (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Rejected by 
spam filter (17211ed8-34a9-11e7-9a8c-336c9f1d8145) [CSP-02])]
                                [1] => 10006
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => /opt/cpanel/ea-
php56/root/usr/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php
                [line] => 319
                [function] => raiseError
                [class] => PEAR
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response 
code received from server (code: 550, response: 5.7.1 Rejected by spam 
filter (17211ed8-34a9-11e7-9a8c-336c9f1d8145) [CSP-02])]
                        [1] => 10006
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [file] => crm/public_html/testsendemail.php
                [line] => 22
                [function] => send
                [class] => Mail_smtp
                [object] => Mail_smtp Object
                    (
                        [_smtp] => Net_SMTP Object
                            (
                                [host] => xxx.com
                                [port] => 25
                                [localhost] => localhost
                                [auth_methods] => Array
                                    (
                                        [LOGIN] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Net_SMTP Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                [1] => authLogin
                                            )

                                        [PLAIN] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Net_SMTP Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                [1] => authPlain
                                            )

                                    )

                                [pipelining] => 
                                [pipelined_commands:protected] => 0
                                [debug:protected] => 
                                [debug_handler:protected] => 
                                [socket:protected] => Net_Socket Object
                                    (
                                        [fp] => Resource id #7
                                        [blocking] => 1
                                        [persistent] => 
                                        [addr] => xxx.com
                                        [port] => 25
                                        [timeout] => 
                                        [lineLength] => 2048
                                        [newline] => 

                                        [_debug] => 
                                        [_default_error_mode] => 
                                        [_default_error_options] => 
                                        [_default_error_handler] => 
                                        [_error_class] => PEAR_Error
                                        [_expected_errors] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [socket_options:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [timeout:protected] => 0
                                [code:protected] => 250
                                [arguments:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Reset OK
                                    )

                                [greeting:protected] => 
sunucu.alvagenyazilim.com ESMTP Exim 4.86 Tue, 09 May 2017 14:17:29 +0300
                                [esmtp:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [sunucu.alvagenyazilim.com] => Hello 
localhost [89.19.23.154]
                                        [SIZE] => 53477376
                                        [8BITMIME] => 
                                        [AUTH] => PLAIN LOGIN
                                        [HELP] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [_extparams] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [host] => xxx.com
                        [port] => 25
                        [auth] => 1
                        [username] => crm@xxx.com
                        [password] => Tansudemir12345
                        [localhost] => localhost
                        [timeout] => 
                        [debug] => 
                        [persist] => 
                        [pipelining] => 
                        [socket_options] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [sep] => 

                        [greeting] => sunucu.alvagenyazilim.com ESMTP Exim 4.86 Tue, 09 May 2017 14:17:29 +0300
                    )

                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ozer@rrrr.com
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [From] => crm@xxx.com
                                [To] => ozer@rrrr.com
                                [Subject] => testemail
                                [Content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
                            )

                        [2] => testemail
                    )

            )

    )

[callback] => 
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add spf and DKIM records in your DNS zone of the domain and also add rDNS record. once done allow it to propagate and check if the mails are still going to spam folder.